# MonoTouch.Dialog - How to get values out of element UI

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a `RootElement` declared and set up how I want on a `DialogViewController`, using the `element-based API` rather than the `reflection API`. Looks great.

However I'm struggling to work out how I can get the values out. Using the reflection-based API this is easy, but I don't see how I can use `BindingContext.Fetch()` with an explicitly declared `RootElement`.

I can't find an example in the samples, nor can I work out how to do this myself.

```
var root = new RootElement(null){
    new Section(){
        new StringElement("Title here"),
        new FloatElement(null, null, 5f)
    }
};

var dv = new DialogViewController(root, true);

dv.ViewDisappearing += delegate {
    // what goes here to get at the value of the FloatElement?
};

NavigationController.PushViewController(dv, true);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't you just traverse your root to find the element you want, then use it's Value property to get the value?

Comment: That's what I thought. But there is no way to uniquely identify one FloatElement from another. So I solved this by adding a Key property to Element - allowing the traversal code to identify a specific element uniquely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store it in a variable, that is scoped where your anonymous method can access it.

Like this:

```
var floatElement = new FloatElement(null, null, 5f);
var root = new RootElement(null){
    new Section(){
        new StringElement("Title here"),
        floatElement,
    }
};

var dv = new DialogViewController(root, true);

dv.ViewDisappearing += delegate {
    //You can access floatElement here
    Console.WriteLine(floatElement.Value);
};

NavigationController.PushViewController(dv, true);
```

Comment: Good way of dealing with it, although you partially lose the nice C# 3.0  initialiser style. Marked as the answer because it works, even though it's not what I ended up doing. (See my comment on the other answer)

Comment: Imo the best solution. Alternatively, keep all the elements in a list, and keep track of the indexes?
Just a suggestion, if you have many elements to handle.